# Can't replicate FFMpeg Prores quality setting

Tags: c, ffmpeg

Using ffmpeg as a library. I'm looking to create a global-quality slider with very inconsistent results. `AvCodecContext::global_quality` seems like a good place to start. Not all lossy codecs make reference to this member, but it does appear to work for ProRes.

```
c:\>ffmpeg.exe -i test.mov -c:v prores_ks -q:v 28 out.mov     # output 10mb file

c:\>ffmpeg.exe -i test.mov -c:v prores_ks -q:v 2 out.mov     # output 28mb file
```

Great. Now let's do it in code. Based on Muxing.c. I'm distilling down the code a lot just to give a hint about which api's I'm calling.

```
AVStream* AddStream(AVFormatContext* formatContext, int quality)
{
    AVCodec* codec = AVFindEncoder("prores_ks");

    AVStream* newStream = avformat_new_stream(formatContext, codec);

    newStream->id = formatContext->nb_streams - 1;

    AVCodecContext c = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);

    c->codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_PRORES;
    c->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
    c->width = 1920;
    c->height = 1080;

    newStream->time_base = av_inv_q(frameRate);
    c->time_base = av_inv_q(frameRate);

    c->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUVA444P10;

    c->global_quality = quality;

    return newStream;
}
......
//excerpt from WriteFrame()

AVPacket pkt;
av_init_packet(&pkt);
pkt.data= pVideoBuffer;
pkt.size= iVideoBufferSize;
int gotpkt = 0;
int ret = avcodec_encode_video2(pCodecContext, &pkt, pPicture, &gotpkt);
if (ret == 0)
{
    av_packet_rescale_ts(&pkt, pCodecContext->time_base, pVideoStream->time_base);

    if (gotpkt) {
        ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(pFormatContext, &pkt);
    }
}
```

I can't get quality to affect the size of the output. Any ideas?

This is the excerpt from proresenc_kostya.c

```
ctx->force_quant = avctx->global_quality / FF_QP2LAMBDA;
if (!ctx->force_quant) {
    if (!ctx->bits_per_mb) {
        for (i = 0; i < NUM_MB_LIMITS - 1; i++)
            if (prores_mb_limits[i] >= ctx->mb_width * ctx->mb_height *
                                       ctx->pictures_per_frame)
                break;
        ctx->bits_per_mb   = ctx->profile_info->br_tab[i];
    } else if (ctx->bits_per_mb < 128) {
        av_log(avctx, AV_LOG_ERROR, "too few bits per MB, please set at least 128\n");
        return AVERROR_INVALIDDATA;
    }

    min_quant = ctx->profile_info->min_quant;
    max_quant = ctx->profile_info->max_quant;
    for (i = min_quant; i < MAX_STORED_Q; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 64; j++)
            ctx->quants[i][j] = ctx->quant_mat[j] * i;
    }

    ctx->slice_q = av_malloc(ctx->slices_per_picture * sizeof(*ctx->slice_q));
    if (!ctx->slice_q) {
        encode_close(avctx);
        return AVERROR(ENOMEM);
    }

    ctx->tdata = av_mallocz(avctx->thread_count * sizeof(*ctx->tdata));
    if (!ctx->tdata) {
        encode_close(avctx);
        return AVERROR(ENOMEM);
    }

    for (j = 0; j < avctx->thread_count; j++) {
        ctx->tdata[j].nodes = av_malloc((ctx->slices_width + 1)
                                        * TRELLIS_WIDTH
                                        * sizeof(*ctx->tdata->nodes));
        if (!ctx->tdata[j].nodes) {
            encode_close(avctx);
            return AVERROR(ENOMEM);
        }
        for (i = min_quant; i < max_quant + 2; i++) {
            ctx->tdata[j].nodes[i].prev_node = -1;
            ctx->tdata[j].nodes[i].bits      = 0;
            ctx->tdata[j].nodes[i].score     = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

*Edit:*

**Outputs from ffmpeg.exe:**

```
profile 4, 1020 slices, interlacing: no, 6576 bits per MB
frame size upper bound: 11429274
```

**Output from ffmpeg avlog on my app:**

```
profile 4, 1020 slices, interlacing: no, 1425 bits per MB
frame size upper bound: 6170103
```

Comment: I believe you need to set c->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_QSCALE;, otherwise it will assume VBR. I admit I didn't actually test it, but it's what ffmpeg_opt.c does when parsing "-q:v".

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. I also noticed that FF_QP2LAMBDA is defined as 118. I don't know why I thought it was 2 or 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some hack supporting older codecs. So the input value is multiplied internally. One needs to do the same as the ffmpeg.exe

```
#define FF_QP2LAMBDA 118

//from ffmpeg_opt.c

ost->enc_ctx->global_quality = FF_QP2LAMBDA * qscale;
```